# Ubuntu 22.10 MT7622 wireless device doesn't work

Tags: wireless, mediatek

I have a problem that has been mentioned many times before, but all the solutions simply won't help...
Please someone help me to finally get my Wifi working on my newly installed System.

I installed only Ubuntu 22.10, no other OS.
Motherboard is ASRock X670E Pro with Mediatek MT7922 Wifi adapter.

I have no Wifi settings.

"~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616] Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616] Kernel modules: mt7921e 0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05) Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1849:8125]"

"sudo dmesg | grep mt7921e" does not give any output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `sudo dmesg | grep mt7921e`

Comment: I tried, but nothing happens

Comment: What do you expect to happen? I ask to run commands and post output to your question. I give up, sry.

Comment: I meant that there is no output after that command.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update firmware for this device. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/mediatek/{WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin,WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin} /lib/firmware/mediatek
```

and reboot.

An update was made upstream but it didn't reach Ubuntu `linux-firmware` yet.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that but still no wifi...

Comment: Please add information I asked for.

Comment: Sorry! did not see that comment

XXXX@whitebox:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616]
 Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616]
 Kernel modules: mt7921e
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
 Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1849:8125]

Comment: Please add information to your question, not to comments.