# Mediatek mt7921e network card not working

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, lspci, mediatek

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 desktop on my Zephyrus Duo 16 GX650PY but I can't get my Wifi card to work.

```
$ lspci -k
04:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e0df
    Kernel modules: mt7921e

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: MEDIATEK Corp.
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fca00000-fcafffff memory:fcb00000-fcb07fff

$ lsmod | grep mt7921e
  mt7921e                28672  0
  mt7921_common          90112  1 mt7921e
  mt76_connac_lib        65536  2 mt7921e,mt7921_common
  mt76                  102400  3 mt7921e,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib

$ inxi -Fza
Network:
Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: gen: 2
 speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8125 class-ID: 0200
IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Device-2: MEDIATEK vendor: Foxconn driver: N/A modules: mt7921e pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s
 lanes: 1 port: N/A bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 14c3:0616 class-ID: 0280
IF-ID-1: enx7eecb1aea0eb state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter>
IF-ID-2: tailscale0 state: unknown speed: -1 duplex: full mac: N/A

$ uname -r
5.19.0-41-generic
```

I tried to look it up and it seems the driver for this network card started having issues from kernel 5.16 onwards and people said a hard reboot was the only solution but it never worked in my case.
I'm dual booting and Fastboot is disabled in the UEFI.
Any idea how I can debug/fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Are you dual-booting the notebook, or is it Ubuntu-only at this point? Have you disabled the "Fast Boot" option in your UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: I'm dual booting and fastboot is disabled. I've edited the original post with more information

Comment: My resources show that your adapter should be using the `mt7922` driver, not `mt7921e`. Was the driver selected by the OS or was it installed manually? 

Comment: It was selected by the OS. How should I change it?

Comment: It may be as simple as `sudo modprobe -r mt7921e` to remove the existing driver, followed by `sudo modprobe mt7922` to set the alternative.

Comment: ```
~ sudo modprobe mt7922
modprobe: FATAL: Module mt7922 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-41-generic
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145937/discussion-between-e-kami-and-matigo).

Comment: For some reason now it's not working in Windows anymore either =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure about your card-model driver and kernel version? I had a similar problems with my g14 zephyrus g14 which has mediatek mt7922 wifi/network card and solved it. Dualboot-ubuntu

Here is the steps and checklist

-> Ubuntu LTS (22.04.2) with Kernel 5.19.0-32-generic (at least 5.17.x required if it is not desired version you should update.
-> lspci output was "network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616"
Then I copied drivers using linux-firmware thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/1456986/1710221

```
sudo apt-install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/mediatek/{WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin,WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin} /lib/firmware/mediatek
```

Then;
Shutdown computer;
Start pc/linux