# Wi-fiadapter not found

Tags: drivers, adapter, mediatek

Mediatek MT7922 (RZ616) my wifi adapter
Ubuntu say me wifi adapter not found
I try install drivers for my adapter it didn’t work out for me, because I didn’t find normal drivers and the driver installation option was only on Windows.
command lspci:
Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
Help me plaece .

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mediatek mt7921e network card not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467514/mediatek-mt7921e-network-card-not-working)