# Issue with MT7922 WiFi Adapter on Ubuntu 22.04 22.10 or 23.10 Daily Build

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus, adapter

Hello Ubuntu community,

I'm facing a problem with my WiFi on Ubuntu 23.10 Daily Build (and older ones) and I need some assistance. I recently purchased a brand new Asus SCAR 17 (Ryzen 9) 2023, which is equipped with an MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless by Mediatek.

Here are the details of the WiFi adapter from the output of the command

sudo lshw -C network:

```
description: Network controller
product: MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=mt7921e latency=0
resources: irq:116 memory:fca00000-fcafffff memory:fcb00000-fcb07ff
```

When checking the dmesg log, I found the following information related to the MT7922 WiFi adapter

sudo dmesg | grep mt79:

```
[7.443366] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: ASIC revision: 79220010
[10.535264] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 1) timeout
[10.535269] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
...
[40.231313] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Message 00000010 (seq 10) timeout
[40.231325] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: Failed to get patch semaphore
[40.312964] mt7921e 0000:04:00.0: hardware init failed
[72.999278] Modules linked in: btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer bnep binfmt_misc zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zzstd(O) zlua(O) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_sof_amd_renoir snd_sof_amd_acp snd_sof_pci snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi snd_hda_intel snd_sof_utils snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c snd_intel_dspcfg snd_soc_core snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41 snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_compress snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls snd_hda_codec ac97_bus cs_dsp snd_hda_core snd_pcm_dmaengine btusb snd_soc_cs35l41_lib snd_hwdep intel_rapl_msr snd_pci_ps mt7921e snd_rpl_pci_acp6x intel_rapl_common btrtl snd_seq_midi mt7921_common snd_acp_pci uvcvideo btbcm snd_seq_midi_event mt76_connac_lib snd_pci_acp6x videobuf2_vmalloc edac_mce_amd btintel snd_rawmidi mt76 snd_pcm videobuf2_memops kvm_amd btmtk snd_seq videobuf2_v4l2
```

Although the operating system recognizes the hardware, it does not appear as a wifi device, and I am unable to utilize it.
What can i do? i noticed some people around here are having same issues without solution.

Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (mantic) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *mantic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 5 October 2023, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 April 2023.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/mantic-minotaur-release-schedule/34989  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: *daily* builds (all releases) are used for QA-testing, and can include packages that are **not** included on *supported* products (even the released products like *jammy* or 22.04.3 as its not yet been released except as 22.04.2 thus the *daily* can include packages found in *-proposed* that are on the *daily* for QA purposes only).  Daily products are not supported on this site.

Comment: I used Daily build out of frustration. As title suggested, even LTE or current build have same identical issue

Comment: Also
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456981/ubuntu-22-10-mt7622-wireless-device-doesnt-work
Says no solution have been found
https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-0616-105b-e0cd
"Detected but not working."