Howo to install wifi drivers without ethernet connection Xiaomi?
I installed ubuntu Os 22.04 LST on my notebook. I have no wifi drivers. I see an error:

No Wi-Fi adapter found

I was reading similar questions and tried command
lspci -knn | grep -iA3 net

Network Controller [0280] Device [0b48:7922]
...
Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconducter Co., LTD RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader ...

What driver should I install?
My laptop model RedmiBook Pro 15 Ryzen Edition Laptop: AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS
UPDATE
Tried command (moved binary file to my PC with help of usb)

wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
chmod +x wireless-info &&
./wireless-info

Result

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Apr 2024 21:56 MSK +0300

Booted last: 29 Apr 2024 00:00 MSK +0300

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Device [0b48:7922]
    Subsystem: Device [0b48:7922]

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 2109:8817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device   
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2b7e:c687 SunplusIT Inc XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 35f5:7922 MediaTek Inc. Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 10a5:9201 FPC FPC Sensor Controller L:0001 FW:021.26.2.045
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    40960  2 video,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         629       1  0 21:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############



UPDATE 2: Was trying command from this answer - Ubuntu 22.10 MT7622 wireless device doesn't work
But it didn't help

You should try 24.04, as AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS is really new.

But where can I find driver binaries?

Most drivers are included with Ubuntu. My hope is that with 24.04 everything should work, and if not, we will need to detect which wireless card is used, and look for drivers.

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

@mikewhatever. added output of the command. What drivers should I install?

@waltinator updated my question with details

Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456981/ubuntu-22-10-mt7622-wireless-device-doesnt-work

@mikewhatever it didn't help. I copied firmware: ``` sudo cp linux-firmware/mediatek/{WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin,WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin} /lib/firmware/mediatek
Restarted, but can't connect to the internet

Well, I would try 24.04, as already suggested.

upgrade the kernel to 6.5

@Jeremy31 how can I upgrade the kernel?

Can you use USB tethering on a smart phone to get internet access to the computer?

@Jeremy31 no
I connected the Ethernet cable, but the Internet does not work.

Create a new file named /etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf and use this for its contents
alias pci:v00000b48d00007922xsv*sd*bc*sc*i* mt7921e
Then make file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mt7921e.rules and add this
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", DEVPATH=="/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e", ATTR{new_id}="0b48 7922"
Save and exit then run sudo depmod -a
Reboot and see if it works

I was trying  echo 0b48 7922 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id
I have an error tee: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id: Invalid argument

Also I was trying sudo echo 0b48 7922 >> /sys/bus/pci/drivers/mt7921e/new_id
And I have an error Permission denied (even for sudo)

I did a big edit, this should get it running

New version didn't help (double checked that filenames and content are correct)

Any results for lsmod | grep 7921
